# How to remove GTA v video memory limit

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, graphics-card

When I was running GTA V on Windows 10, it ran fine, but later I changed Windows to 8.1 and now when I try to run GTA V, it displays an alert that my video card is out of memory. In the GTA V settings, it only shows 930/512 MB (of Video Memory).

Why is this? I have a 2 GB graphics card but GTA V is detecting only 512 MB. This is making GTA V lag with Windows 8.1 when it didn't lag with Windows 10.

Comment: Are you playing on a laptop?

Comment: yes I'm playing it on laptop

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on a laptop, it is very possible that you are using the integrated gpu, rather than the much more powerful dedicated nvidia gpu.
You can change it in the nvidia control panel in the "Manage 3D settings" menu like this:
[image: screenshot of the nvidia 3D settings window]
To get to this window, you have to right click on your desktop and open "Nvidia control panel".
Make sure you pick GTA V in the dropdown list of programs you're changing this setting for. If it's not there, you can add the .exe by clicking the "Add" button and finding the .exe of GTA V.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is no having nVidia control panel!!!

Comment: @AnsariAbdullah Install your video drivers then ... GO to nvidia's site and download the video driver. After it's done installing it should be fine without doing the steps explained in this answer, if its still not then do them.

Comment: There's a slim chance OP has an AMD gpu in the laptop, but that seems very unlikely as the higher end ones are very rare and the lower end ones don't have a separate integrated gpu, so this issue wouldn't occur in the first place. Seems very likely that the OP hasn't installed official drivers since he reinstalled windows.